Rotate container using the rotate icon in flutter
I have one resizable container. When drag the rotate icon rotate container with the all resizable point update and the rotate icon position also change with rotation.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Movable Image Box'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: MovableImageBox(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MovableImageBox extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MovableTextBoxState createState() => _MovableTextBoxState();
}

const ballDiameter = 15.0;
const rotateIconSize = 30.0;

class _MovableTextBoxState extends State<MovableImageBox> {
  double width = 150;
  double height = 100;
  double aspectRatio = 100 / 150;
  bool _isSelected = true;
  double top = 100;
  double left = 100;
  Offset? startRotationPosition;
  double _angle = 0.0;
  double _oldAngle = 0.0;
  double _angleDelta = 0.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(children: [
      Transform.rotate(
        angle: _angle,
        child: Stack(children: [
          Positioned(
            top: top,
            left: left,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  _isSelected = true;
                });
              },
              onPanDown: (details) {
                setState(() {
                  FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                  _isSelected = true;
                });
              },
              onPanUpdate: (details) {
                setState(() {
                  top += details.delta.dy;
                  left += details.delta.dx;
                });
              },

                child: Container(
                  height: height,
                  width: width,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    border: Border.all(
                      width: 2,
                      color: _isSelected ? Colors.black : Colors.transparent,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          

          // Rotate Icon
          Positioned(
            top: top - rotateIconSize / 2 - 50,
            left: left + width / 2 - rotateIconSize / 2,
            child: Column(children: [
              Transform.rotate(
                angle: _angle,
                child: Container(
                  width: 30,
                  height: 30,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                  ),
                  child: LayoutBuilder(
                    builder: (context, constraints) {
                      Offset centerOfGestureDetector =
                          Offset(width / 2, height / 2);
                      return GestureDetector(
                        // behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                        onPanStart: (details) {
                          final touchPositionFromCenter =
                              details.localPosition - centerOfGestureDetector;
                          _angleDelta =
                              _oldAngle - touchPositionFromCenter.direction;
                        },
                        onPanEnd: (details) {
                          setState(
                            () {
                              _oldAngle = _angle;
                            },
                          );
                        },
                        onPanUpdate: (details) {
                          final touchPositionFromCenter =
                              details.localPosition - centerOfGestureDetector;

                          setState(
                            () {
                              _angle = touchPositionFromCenter.direction +
                                  _angleDelta;
                            },
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ]),
          ),

          // top left
          if (_isSelected)
            Positioned(
              top: top - ballDiameter / 2,
              left: left - ballDiameter / 2,
              child: ManipulatingBall(
                onDrag: (dx, dy) {
                  var newWidth = width - dx;
                  var newHeight = newWidth * aspectRatio;
                  setState(() {
                    if (newHeight > 10 && newWidth > 10) {
                      top = top + (height - newHeight);
                      left = left + dx;
                      height = newHeight;
                      width = newWidth;
                    }
                  });
                },
                handlerWidget: HandlerWidget.VERTICAL,
              ),
            ),
          //top mid
          if (_isSelected && (width > 10 && height > 10))
            Positioned(
              top: top - ballDiameter / 2,
              left: left + width / 2 - ballDiameter / 2,
              child: ManipulatingBall(
                onDrag: (dx, dy) {
                  var newHeight = height - dy;
                  var newTop = top + dy;
                  setState(() {
                    if (newHeight > 10 && newTop >= 0) {
                      height = newHeight;
                      top = newTop;
                    }
                  });
                  // cropImage(0, dy);
                },
                handlerWidget: HandlerWidget.HORIZONTAL,
              ),
            ),
          // top right
          if (_isSelected && (width > 10 && height > 10))
            Positioned(
              top: top - ballDiameter / 2,
              left: left + width - ballDiameter / 2,
              child: ManipulatingBall(
                onDrag: (dx, dy) {
                  var newWidth = width + dx;
                  var newHeight = newWidth * aspectRatio;
                  setState(() {
                    if (newHeight > 10 && newWidth > 10) {
                      top = top + (height - newHeight);
                      height = newHeight;
                      width = newWidth;
                    }
                  });
                },
                handlerWidget: HandlerWidget.VERTICAL,
              ),
            ),
          //bottom righ
          if (_isSelected && (width > 10 && height > 10))
            Positioned(
              top: top + height - ballDiameter / 2,
              left: left + width - ballDiameter / 2,
              child: ManipulatingBall(
                onDrag: (dx, dy) {
                  var newWidth = width + dx;
                  var newHeight = newWidth * aspectRatio;
                  setState(() {
                    // isCorner = true;
                    if (newHeight > 10 && newWidth > 10) {
                      height = newHeight;
                      width = newWidth;
                    }
                  });
                },
                handlerWidget: HandlerWidget.VERTICAL,
              ),
            ),
          //bottom left
          if (_isSelected && (width > 10 && height > 10))
            Positioned(
              top: top + height - ballDiameter / 2,
              left: left - ballDiameter / 2,
              child: ManipulatingBall(
                onDrag: (dx, dy) {
                  var newWidth = width - dx;
                  var newHeight = newWidth * aspectRatio;
                  setState(() {
                    if (newHeight > 10 && newWidth > 10) {
                      height = newHeight;
                      width = newWidth;
                      top = top + (height - newHeight);
                      left = left + dx;
                    }
                  });
                },
                handlerWidget: HandlerWidget.VERTICAL,
              ),
            ),
          //bottom mid
          if (_isSelected && (width > 10 && height > 10))
            Positioned(
              top: top + height - ballDiameter / 2,
              left: left + width / 2 - ballDiameter / 2,
              child: ManipulatingBall(
                onDrag: (dx, dy) {
                  var newHeight = height + dy;
                  setState(() {
                    if (newHeight > 10) {
                      height = newHeight;
                    }
                  });
                },
                handlerWidget: HandlerWidget.HORIZONTAL,
              ),
            ),
        ]),
      ),
    ]);
  }
}

class ManipulatingBall extends StatefulWidget {
  ManipulatingBall(
      {Key? key, required this.onDrag, required this.handlerWidget});

  final Function onDrag;
  final HandlerWidget handlerWidget;

  @override
  _ManipulatingBallState createState() => _ManipulatingBallState();
}

enum HandlerWidget { HORIZONTAL, VERTICAL }

class _ManipulatingBallState extends State<ManipulatingBall> {
  late double initX;
  late double initY;

  _handleDrag(details) {
    setState(() {
      initX = details.globalPosition.dx;
      initY = details.globalPosition.dy;
    });
  }

  _handleUpdate(details) {
    var dx = details.globalPosition.dx - initX;
    var dy = details.globalPosition.dy - initY;
    initX = details.globalPosition.dx;
    initY = details.globalPosition.dy;
    widget.onDrag(dx, dy);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onPanStart: _handleDrag,
      onPanUpdate: _handleUpdate,
      child: Container(
        width: ballDiameter,
        height: ballDiameter,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.black,
          shape: this.widget.handlerWidget == HandlerWidget.VERTICAL
              ? BoxShape.circle
              : BoxShape.rectangle,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

I have one resizable container. When drag the rotate icon rotate container with the all resizable point update and the rotate icon position also change with rotation.
i have this type container


which type of changes need?

you can start with this: https://gist.github.com/pskink/a8a497c11365e65dda48648ac07e302b#file-flow_resizer_minimal-dart, the main idea is to use Flow widget

i have see your code but no idea what i change. i have to set rotation in my code(i post code).

i also rotation function add but when rotate the container is rotate but the resizable point not update how to do top and left position for change.

have you seen the code I linked? it has _rotate method - check how it is implemented

i have add rotate method but how to resize point update when container rotate

see _resize

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

import 'flow_painting_context_extension.dart';   what is this any pacakge or file?? its give error.

i have update code and add rotate icon logic but now how to my all resizable point update. (updated code in the question edit)

they will update automatically if you make them as children of Transform.rotate

but in this code how to make them as children..?

use Transform.rotate with Stack as a child - this Stack should have 8 children that are used for resizing - now if you change angle in Transform.rotate all 8 sizers will rotate too

when i rotate container 180 degree that time my container top mid point go down as like bottom mid when that time i this point go down side the container height decrease but i have to in real case hight increase how to fix i have update the code how to solve this?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78483721/how-to-show-dotted-line-when-container-move-in-flutter
